# Firefox and Thunderbird can't read /usr to add apps to handlers file

Tags: permissions, firefox, thunderbird

In some recent update I lost all the application handlers in both Firefox and Thunderbird. When I search for "other apps" it reports no permission to access /usr. The directory has 755 permissions, however.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Are these applications installed as snap? Check if they appear in the output of `snap list`. If it are snaps, indeed they cannot access /usr.

Comment: It's 21.10. Firefox is installed via snap. Thunderbird behaves that way whether the Ubuntu version via apt or a direct binary download. Firefox only started behaving this way recently.

Comment: Please add all info that can be relevant to the question: use "edit".

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Firefox in Ubuntu 21.10 (can't really read `usr/` even though the permissions are fine).
As stated in the comments, the problem is the snap.
So remove the Firefox snap and re-install it via apt.

```
sudo snap remove firefox
sudo apt install firefox
```

(It remains a mystery to me why Ubuntu has Firefox snap by default, since it is flawed)

Comment: 21.10 has snap as default? I have 20.04 and it has both Firefox and Thunderbird as regular deb packages.